# Go to definition is not working in visual studio 2015 (Specially in Javascript user defined functions)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015

I did everything starting from deleting the .suo file and restarting it and installing every extensions like web essentials and GotoDefinition, deleted the tmp files (have also installed the VS update 1) but all in vain nothing works.
Like for example if there is a user defined function like`preparemandatoryfield()` which I defined in Script.js file and if I press f12 on `preparemandatoryfield()` it says

> go to definition failed either because the caret is already at the definition
>   error.
>   This Goto definition specifically doesnt work in javascript functions but works everywhere in VS 2015.

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this? i'm facing the same problem in VS 2015 update 2.

Comment: Not yet, I think the problem is with VS 2015, it works fine in previous versions it works fine in the same .js file but if you want to  find the function from elsewhere it doesn't work... :(

Answer (score 6):

Also encountered this bug. Disabling/enabling extensions not helps.
Besides got to definition not worked, intellisense stopped for me.

I reset my _references.js file and this solved the problem. Cleared the content the file and leaved only:

```
/// <autosync enabled="true" />
```

(Found that the guilty script is the jquery ui library. Removed any jquery ui related script  from _references.js and this solved the problem. I'm not used the full jquery ui script file, instead a custom built one by the theme roller.)

Comment: Thank you Sir, Removing the jquery-ui reference from the _references.js file did the trick. Awesome!!

Comment: This answer saved my coding day.  I removed any jquery ui reference path in _references.js and the intellisense are working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in VS2015. Switched to VS2017 and it works.